# chmod: removing "x" permission recursively totally borks the permissions

Tags: chmod

I have a folder with some contents (three files and a folder) that look like this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 max max 14504 2011-05-31 16:55 main.css
-rwxr-xr-x 1 max max  2504 2011-05-31 16:55 reset.css
-rwxr-xr-x 1 max max   916 2011-05-31 16:55 scaffold.css
drwxrwxr-x 3 max max  4096 2011-05-31 16:55 ui-lightness
```

I want to add group write to all of them and remove the executable status for all users.  I do the files first:

```
$ chmod g+w main.css reset.css scaffold.css 
$ chmod a-x main.css reset.css scaffold.css 
$ ls -l
total 28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max 14504 2011-05-31 16:55 main.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  2504 2011-05-31 16:55 reset.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max   916 2011-05-31 16:55 scaffold.css
drwxrwxr-x 3 max max  4096 2011-05-31 16:55 ui-lightness
```

So far so good.  Now, the ui-lightness folder already has group write, so i just want to remove exe status from it and all the files and subfolders inside.

```
$ ls -l ui-lightness/
total 40
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max  4096 2011-05-31 16:55 images
-rwxrwxr-x 1 max max 34146 2011-05-31 16:55 jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css

$ chmod -R a-x ui-lightness/
chmod: cannot access `ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `ui-lightness/images': Permission denied

$ ls -l ui-lightness/
ls: cannot access ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css: Permission denied
ls: cannot access ui-lightness/images: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? images
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css
$
```

My first instinct is to panic a bit.  But, adding the x status back on fixes it!

```
$ chmod -R a+x ui-lightness/

$ ls -l ui-lightness/
total 40
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max  4096 2011-05-31 16:55 images
-rwxrwxr-x 1 max max 34146 2011-05-31 16:55 jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?  And how i remove the executable status without borking everything?  This is in ubuntu 9.10 in case that's relevant.

cheers, max

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first parameter to your recursive chmod is the directory itself. You removed x bit on the directory, making it not searchable any more (that's what the x bit does for a directory). Then the chmod program could no longer search inside that directory and you get the permissions errors. try the following instead.

```
chmod -R a-x ui-lightness/*
```

Comment: ahhh - so directories need to have the x property then?  I did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: But, then, if i do `chmod -R a-x ui-lightness/*`, and there's another subdir inside that, then *that* subdir will get borked, right?

Comment: yes. You really should be using `find . -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;` to select only regular files.

Answer (score 12):

To remove executable status only for files, use:

```
$ chmod -R a-x+X ui-lightness/
```

The `+X` option is defined (see `man chmod`) to:

> - set execute permission only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user

So, the lowercase `-x` option first removes the executable status from all files (and directories, of course), then the uppercase `+X` option sets it back only for directories.

It has one minor drawback: it sets the executable status to **all** subdirectories, even to those that didn't have it set prior to the `chmod` invocation. If that's not what you want, just use Keith's `find` solution.

Comment: this works perfectly with nested directories!